# The word "logo" is appearing in all the search results for my site, but it's not in my page titles

Tags: php, html, google-search, search-results, title

When I search for my website in Google, the word "logo" is being displayed in all the results, but I didn't specify the word "logo" in the titles of my HTML pages.

See the following screenshot:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why the word "logo" might be appearing in the search results for my site like this?

Comment: You most probably add the word *logo* through PHP (or another server programming language) in <title> tag of all your pages.

Comment: no i haven't added in php title tags

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you have an image with the alt "logo". Google can prepend/append text to titles if it thinks your titles don't meet their standards. And based on the results you show in the screenshot, your titles aren't very good, so it appends some text.

In this case it decided that the word 'logo' represents you.

**How to fix:**

- Change alt to "Logo [yourName]". It's alternative text, logo is too broad
- [Make decent titles](http://moz.com/learn/seo/title-tag)
- Play the waiting game.

Comment: Good guess. Loking at the source code, "logo" is indeed used as the `alt` attribute for the images on each page, and the titles are short boilerplates. The OP should consider branding titles as discussed [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en), and use the Fetch as Google tool in Google Webmaster Tools to trigger crawling after they're corrected.

Comment: The `img alt="logo"` is also the very first bit of content in the source on every page. Consider implementing the logo as a `background-image` on other pages (except maybe the home page)?